# Time based workflow is not firing Email as per the condition

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

[image]Hi I have developed a Time Based workflow rule with the Evaluation Criteria "**Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria**" The Criteria is If case.Priority is equal to normal and Case.Staus is not equal to Closed then trigger a Email after 5 days of the Date/Time Opened of the Case.

The issue is even before the 5 days or After 5 days the email will trigger even if the Status is Equal to closed (However the condition is If the Case.Status is not equal to closed.)

The status can be seen here:
[image]

Comment: Did you check what is the status or workflow has been fired or not by checking at setup>> monitor>> time based workflow. ?

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of your criteria and a screenshot of a case in the list above where the status is now closed?? Also note that if the WFR was updated AFTER the case triggered the queue it will NOT be canceled unless it is edited again. (i.e. criteria did not include closed, a case in the queue was closed, criteria updated to exclude closed, case would still be in queue until it is edited again)

Comment: Hi Eric the screen shot you are seeing is the list of queued Workflow, But the issue is , for some cases which was already closed within 5 days, the workflow fires even th status is closed, but the criteria set is If Case priority is normal and Status not equal to closed then it should trigger mail.

Comment: Eric You can find the workflow Criteria Screen shot in the question